# C#/Xamarin Constructor new Java Object

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Need to use C#/Xamarin to use a Java library.

Java

```
class MyObject{
    private final string1;
    private final Date date;
    public MyObject(final String string1, final Date date){
        //init here
    }
}
```

In the generated .cs file...

```
namespace Com.MyPackage{
    internal MyObject(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer){}

    static IntPtr id_getString1;
    public unsafe string String1{
        [Register ("getString1", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "GetString1Handler")]

        get{
            if(id_getString1 == IntPtr.Zero){
                id_getString1 = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "getString1", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
                try{
                    return JNIEnv.GetString(JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_getString1), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                }finally{
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

OK, so it is internal. So I make a new method and changed it to this:

```
namespace Com.MyPackage{
    public MyObject(Java.Lang.String string1, Java.Util.Date dateIntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer){
        String1 = string1; //error
    }

    static IntPtr id_getString1;
    public unsafe string String1{
        [Register ("getString1", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "GetString1Handler")]

        get{
            if(id_getString1 == IntPtr.Zero){
                id_getString1 = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "getString1", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
                try{
                    return JNIEnv.GetString(JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_getString1), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                }finally{
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

This causes the error

> Property or indexer 'MyObject.String1' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

This is how I am trying to get a new instance in C#.

```
IntPtr Map_Class = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/myPackage/MyObject");
IntPtr Map_defCtor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(Map_Class, "<init>", "(Java.Lang.String, Java.Util.Date)V");
IntPtr ptr = JNIEnv.NewObject(Map_Class, Map_defCtor);
MyObject myObject = new MyObject("hello world", new Java.Util.Date(123),
        ptr, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef
).JavaCast<MyObject>();
```

Comment: Nothing wrong. I just don't know how to assign the final variables for Java's Constructor. How do I call the Constructor in Java from C# correctly?

Comment: Still confused, are you saying there is no matching C# `.actor` for the Java one in the generated binding?